# How to convert PHAsset to UIImage in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, uiimage

I have an array filled with `PHAsset` objects (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html), and I want to know how I can convert them into a UIImage and then save them in an Array.

The array with the PHAsset objects is called `self.assets` and here is what I have so far:

```
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];

CGFloat scale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;

NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.assets count]];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.assets count]; i++) {

    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(scale, scale);

    [manager requestImageForAsset:[self.assets objectAtIndex:i]
                       targetSize:targetSize
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                          options:self.requestOptions
                    resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info){
                        [images addObject:image];
                    }];
}
```

self.requestOptions is a property in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions;
```

and in the viewDidLoad I am doing this:

```
self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
```

But after doing some debugging, I keep seeing that `self.assets` has the following values:

```
(
<PHAsset: 0x1743828a0> 3B6D658D-EC76-43A1-9793-35D889E9CF15/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, assetSource=3, (2448x2448), creationDate=2015-07-27 02:02:46 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 ,
<PHAsset: 0x174382970> 50F05575-71D2-446B-BD1E-8E3250E375AD/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, assetSource=3, (2448x2448), creationDate=2015-07-27 02:02:47 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 
)
```

and `images` is empty. Does anyone know how I can add convert the PHAssets into UIImages and add them to the `images` array? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For anyone struggling as much as I had on this issue, this is the way to go.

First set the requestOptions as:

```
self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

// this one is key
self.requestOptions.synchronous = YES;
```

and if there are multiple assets in an array filled with PHAsset objects, then add this code:

```
self.assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:assets];
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[assets count]];

// assets contains PHAsset objects.
 __block UIImage *ima;

for (PHAsset *asset in self.assets) {
    // Do something with the asset

    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                       targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                          options:self.requestOptions
                    resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                        ima = image;

                        [images addObject:ima];
                    }];


}
```

and now the `images` array contains all the images in `uiimage` format.

Comment: This code does not work! UIImage *image which is returned via resultHandler is always nil.

Comment: Give this man a cookie.  requestOptions.synchronous = YES;  This fixed my mysterious error when requesting an asset.  `[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3.0 Answer

```
let photoAsset = asset
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        var options: PHImageRequestOptions?
        options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options?.resizeMode = .exact
        options?.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImage(
            for: photoAsset,
            targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
            contentMode: .aspectFill,
            options: options
        ) { [weak self] result, _ in
            completion(result)
        }
```

**options?.isSynchronous = true** is very important

```
BOOL synchronous; // return only a single result, blocking until available (or failure). Defaults to NO
```

Comment: ** isSynchronous**

If false (the default), the requestImage(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:) method returns immediately. Depending on the deliveryMode property, Photos may call your resultHandler block before the method returns, at some later time, or both.

If true, the requestImage(for:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:) method blocks the calling thread until image data is ready or an error occurs. Photos calls your result handler block exactly once.

>Note
Perform synchronous requests from a background thread only.

Comment: How to convert PHAsset to UIImage *in Objective-C*

Comment: hey @JamesWolfe you can see the above answer by Shalin Shah. it is in objective-c

Answer (score -1):

image may be nil(seldom). It's better to evaluate, otherwise array add nil will crash app.

```
if(image){
    ima = image;
    [images addObject:ima];
}
```

Comment: Literally 0 context given to this answer, just a random bit of code checking if an unknown variable is nil.